# bad install directory path

Tags: wix, directory, installation, windows-installer

I am creating a setup project in WiX, I've used WixUI_Common as a base and extended it with my custom dialogs. But when the user gets to the InstallDirDlg dialog, the installation path is "C:\", and this is totally unacceptable. Although previously in the code I've set:

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
            <Component  Id="Component_SetupCM.wxs" Guid="60A58B24-CA71-44CE-947F-6BBDC7C6C89C" >
                <File Source="Product.wxs" Id="Product.wxs" KeyPath="yes"/>
            </Component>
        </Directory>
<Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="TARGETDIR" />
```

So what could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

you need something like this:

```
<DirectoryRef Id = TARGETDIR>
  <Directory Id = "ProgramFilesFolder">
    <Directory Id = "INSTALLDIR" Name = "MyAppName"/>
  </Directory>
</Directory>

<Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="INSTALLDIR" />
```

The problem you are have is that TARGETDIR = c:\

UPDATE:
As long as you have the line

```
<Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="TARGETDIR" />
```

You will continue to have the same problem.  TARGETDIR = c:\ and it always will.
Notice in my example I set WIXUI_INSTALLDIR to INSTALLDIR and not TARGETDIR.  The problem with your code was not the directory structure so much as that you were setting WIXUI_INSTALLDIR to the wrong value.  My solution above works as I copied it from a project I'm currently using.

Comment: I've updated my answer. If it doesn't work post your directory structure and the property assignment for WIXUI_INSTALLDIR and I should be able to tell you why its not working.  For all intents and purposes your new solution is exactly the same as the original.